# How to disable range selector from highstocks charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to disable the from - to range selector that comes by default in highstocks. Looked up the api documentation but didn't find a solution. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your chart config, set [`rangeSelector.inputEnabled`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.inputEnabled) false.

Comment: It doesn't work because I think it's for an older syntax. Would be best to check how it works directly on the site. https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.enabled

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer will only disable the Range Selector;

If you want to remove it completely, you need:

```
 rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
},
```

Comment: This is currently the correct way to be used on highstock.

Answer (score 9):

you can use add inputEnabled:false

```
rangeSelector : {
   inputEnabled:false
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use for StockChart just like below:

```
this.chartData = new StockChart({
  title: {
    text: 'Data Chart'
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0,
    inputEnabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    },
    name: 'Chart',
    data: [],
    type: undefined
  }]
});
```